# JAVA Вернуть два массива из одного метода и прочитать в другом

Tags: java

В одном метода, делаю sql запрос для получения ряда данных. Все эти данные формирую в отчет и в массив. Но для продолжения работы, мне нужен например id каждого отчета, из этой же базы. Можно ли как-то сложить два массива в один(что-то ? ) и сделать ему return, а в другом методе другого класса, достать по очерёдно то, что мне нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Часто в языках программирования для этого используются т.н. кортежи (tuples). В Java, к сожалению, их нет (хотя в 14 появились record, которые достаточно близки и могли бы использоваться для этой задачи).

Но это легко обходится при помощи вспомогательного класса. Например, простейший кортеж на два значения:

```
public final class Tuple2<A, B> {
    private final A v1;
    private final B v2;
    public Tuple2(A v1, B v2) {
        this.v1 = v1;
        this.v2 = v2;
    }
    public A get1() {
        return v1;
    }

    public B get2() {
        return v2;
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
public class Main {
    public static Tuple2<String[], int[]> test() {
        String[] arr1 = {"a", "b", "c"};
        int[] arr2 = {1, 2, 3};
        return new Tuple2(arr1, arr2);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Tuple2<String[], int[]> result = test();
        String[] arr1 = result.get1();
        int[] arr2 = result.get2();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это пока то что нужно.стоит ли смотреть на record или он никаких преимуществ не дает?

Comment: record позволит проще определять классы, подобные этому `Tuple2`, но требования к версии Java сильно повышается. Какого-то принципиального новшества там нет.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо